# Mysql Stored Proceedure: DEFINER=`root`@`%` is not working in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have searched on this problem a lot but could not find solution.

I am using stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetImages`(
in search Varchar(80)
)
BEGIN
select  
image_path
from check_images
where checkNumber=search;

END
```

It is not working in localhost and getting following Error:

> Error Number: 1449
>
> The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist

But if I replace % sign with "localhost" ('root'@'localhost') then everything works perfect. Also I am not allowed to alter the stored procedure. So please tell me the best solution that how can I overcome this problem.

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message is quite clear that user does not exist.

In MySQL a user account consists of both the user name and the host definition component.

Either change the definer to `'root'@'localhost'` or create a user for `'root'@'%'`

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply.
I want to chose the second option, creating the user. Can you please give hint that what I can do for creating user for 'root'@'%' ?

Comment: Great, You helped me a lot, I fixed it because of you. Thank you so much

Comment: @user3043360 Glad to help. I should have noted that typically setting up root access from anywhere besides localhost is frowned upon as a security vulnerability. Really, in most cases, applications should not be using `root` at all, but should have application-specific users defined.